# Looking for solid state switch

Tags: switches, relay, triac

I'm looking for a switch like element. I want to use it with DC, but intend to use it to charge and discharge a capacitor.
A triac would seemingly be perfect, however, I did a bunch of LTSpice simulations using it and they didn't work as intended.
I want to make a circuit that is a battery balancer. (Using capacitors in the simulation)
The idea is to charge a capacitor (on the left) by shorting it to the + and - of one of 2 capacitors in series (on the right). Then, once it's charged, I'd connect the capacitor to the terminals of the second capacitor and thus charge it a bit more...then repeat the process.
Since the situation can be reversed and the second cap could be the one with the higher voltage (aka less capacitance charges faster), the switch would charge the capacitor on the left and then discharge it into the first capacitor. (This is why I want it to be bidirectional)
Instead of physically connecting and disconnecting the cap on the left, I want to use 6 "switches" that I can digitally control, turning them on/off and thus charge the cap on the left from and into the caps on the right.
I'm sure a relay would work, but I was wondering if a solid-state version exists. [image]

Comment: Solid-state relays exist and are not terribly expensive. They're basically just optocouplers with aspirations.

Comment: What's wrong with off-the-shelf balancer circuits?

Comment: @Hearth I'm pretty sure an optocoupler wouldn't work because of the voltage drop. Since I want to balance the capacitors "exactly", the 0,7V drop isn't something I can neglect.

Comment: @CrtSuznik the only significant voltage drop in an opto (as long as you use a FET-based one anyway) is on the control side, not the switched side.

Comment: @Hearth Aaaah, I see. I'm guessing they work the same as a mosfet then? In which case wouldn't the body diode mess everything up and conduct when they're not supposed to?
I thought the triac solution was perfect since they even stop conducting when the current is too low, but that would only be the case when the charge transfer would be done anyway.

Comment: @CrtSuznik See my answer.

Comment: Standard triacs will stay on, once fired, until the current falls below a minimum threshold. Might that be a problem for your intended use?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm sure a relay would work, but I was wondering if a solid-state version exists.

Fortunately for you, there's a device called a [solid-state relay](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/solid-state-relays/183)!. They're basically optocouplers with aspirations, so they're pretty cheap.

I'd use a MOSFET type to avoid the difficulties of a triac-type SSR.

To address the concerns about the body diode brought up in the comments: take a look at this picture (from [this datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83836/lh1546adf.pdf), for a generic cheap SSR)

[image: schematic symbol for an optocoupler from a Vishay datasheet. It has an LED on one side of the isolation barrier and two back-to-back MOSFETs with their sources and gates tied together on the other.]

Notice how there's two FETs in series, with their body diodes back to back. This configuration works because of the optical isolation for the gates; you couldn't use this in a conventional circuit without a properly designed driver. Since they're back to back, when the SSR is turned off, one body diode will always be reverse-biased.